# Node.js, express.js and a json file

Tags: json, node.js, express

I'd like some help please, my node/express knowledge is very limited but I'm just trying to do something which is quite basic, which if it were C# I'd have no problem with.

Assuming the following json data structure, how do I display the count of items where the "currentstage" = "Beta" using node.js and output the value to a template using express.js? Nothing gets returned no matter what I try, even just a plain string.

Json:

```
{
"items":[
    {
        "currentstage": "Beta",
        "title": "This will be the title",
        "body": "This will be the body text",
        "externallink": "http://example.com",
        "contact": "John Does",
        "stages":[
            {
                "Alpha":[{
                    "description": "Started alpha",
                    "start": "2018-01-01"
                }]
            },
            {
                "Beta":[{
                    "description": "Started beta",
                    "start": "2018-04-01"
                }]
            }
        ]
    }
    {
        "currentstage": "Alpha",
        "title": "This will be the title",
        "body": "This will be the body text",
        "externallink": "http://example.com",
        "contact": "John Does",
        "stages":[
            {
                "Alpha":[{
                    "description": "Started alpha",
                    "start": "2018-03-01"
                }]
            }
        ]
    }
]
}
```

Route.js
The json file is in the same folder as the routes.js file

```
exports.index = function (req, res) {
  var obj = require('projectdata.json'); 
res.render('index', { items: obj.filter(function(value) { return value.currentstage === "Beta" }).length } );  
};
```

index.html

```
<p>Items at Beta: {{items}}</p>
```

Comment: Place a console.log(obj) in the main.js file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should iterate over the `obj.items` array instead of the object `obj` containing the items array:

```
obj.items.filter(function(value) { return value.currentstage === "Beta" }).length
```